# What does the 'property_type' key do in hook_field_info()?

Tags: 7, entities

If you look at [the hook_field_info()](http://drupalcode.org/project/physical.git/blob/32e1a38:/physical.module) from [Physical Fields](http://drupal.org/project/physical) the returned array has two keys that aren't mentioned in [the documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_info/7): `property_type` and `property_callbacks`. Can anyone explain what these are for? (Bonus question, are there any other missing keys in the documentation?!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They're not part of Drupal core, but are extra keys provided/used by the [Entity Module](http://drupal.org/project/entity). The comments in entity.api.php clear it up quite nicely:

> For providing entity property info for fields each field type may specify a property type to map to in its field info using the key 'property_type'. With that info in place useful defaults are generated, which is already suiting for a lot of field types.
>
> However it's possible to specify further callbacks, that may alter the generated property info. To do so use the key 'property_callbacks' and set it to an array of function names. Apart from that any property info provided for a field instance using the key 'property info' is added in too.

I'm afraid I don't know of any other undocumented keys, but a comment in the same file just above the previous ones notes:

> This is a placeholder for describing further keys for hook_field_info(), which are introduced by the entity API.

I would just keep your eye on that file when future versions of the Entity module come out to see if any new ones have been added; `property_type` and `property_callbacks` are the only ones mentioned at the time of writing.