# Can't access custom field through entity_metadata_wrapper

Tags: entities

I've created a custom field and widget with the Field API. I've added this custom field to one of my node entities by using the Field UI and named it field_pec_uuid. However, when i try to access the values of this field by using entity_metadata_wrapper like so:

```
$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $nid);
print $node_wrapper->field_pec_uuid->value();
```

It will give me the following error:

```
EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property field_pec_uuid. in EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo() (regel 335 van /webroot/d7_root/sites/all/modules/contrib/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).
```

When I print the values of $node_wrapper->value() I can clearly see the field exists and even has the value I've been giving it. However, when I print the values of $node_wrapper->getPropertyInfo() I can see the field name is not listed. What am I missing here? Anyone has any indications?

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get my field listed by $node_wrapper->getPropertyInfo(). Below is my code.

```
/**
 * Field & Widget section
 */

/**
 * Implementation of hook_field_info()
 * 
 * @return [type] [description]
 */
function poh_eduref_field_info() {
  return array(
    'eduref_uuid' => array(
      'label' => t('Eduref UUID Field'),
      'description' => t('This field stores UUID values.'),
      'settings' => array('allowed_values' => array(), 'allowed_values_function' => ''),
      'default_widget' => 'poh_eduref_eduref_widget',
      'default_formatter' => 'poh_eduref_field_formatter_view',
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_info
 * 
 * @return [type] [description]
 */
function poh_eduref_field_widget_info() {
  return array(
    'poh_eduref_eduref_widget' => array(
      'label' => t('Education Reference Field'),
      'field types' => array('eduref_uuid'),
      'settings' => array(
        'autocomplete_path' => 'eduref/autocomplete',
      ),
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_form()
 * 
 * @param  [type] &$form       [description]
 * @param  [type] &$form_state [description]
 * @param  [type] $field       [description]
 * @param  [type] $instance    [description]
 * @param  [type] $langcode    [description]
 * @param  [type] $items       [description]
 * @param  [type] $delta       [description]
 * @param  [type] $element     [description]
 * @return [type]              [description]
 */
function poh_eduref_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {
  $item =& $items[$delta];

  $element['uuid'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => $element['#title'],
    '#description' => t('This is the description.'),
  );

  $element['uuid']['value'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Education Reference',
    '#autocomplete_path' => $instance['widget']['settings']['autocomplete_path'],
    '#default_value' => isset($item['value']) ? $item['value'] : '',
  );

  return $element;
}

function poh_eduref_field_presave($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, &$items) {
  if($field['type'] == 'eduref_uuid') {
    foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
      if (isset($item['uuid']['value'])) {
        $items[$delta]['value'] = $item['uuid']['value'];
      }
    }
  }
}

/**
 * [poh_eduref_autocomplete_callback description]
 * @param  [type] $string [description]
 * @return [type]         [description]
 */
function poh_eduref_autocomplete_callback($string) {

  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $result = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'poheduref')
  ->fieldCondition('field_eduref_display_name', 'value', $string.'%', 'LIKE')
  ->execute();

  if($result['node']) {
    foreach(array_keys($result['node']) as $nid) {
      $node = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $nid);
      if($node->field_eduref_uuid && $node->field_eduref_display_name) {
        $json_array[$node->field_eduref_uuid->value()] = $node->field_eduref_disorder->value().'/'.$node->field_eduref_type->value().'/'.$node->field_eduref_display_name->value();
      }
    }
  }

  return drupal_json_output($json_array);
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_field_is_empty()
 * 
 * @param  [type] $item  [description]
 * @param  [type] $field [description]
 * @return [type]        [description]
 */
function poh_eduref_field_is_empty($item, $field) {
  $temp = array_keys($field['columns']);
  $key = array_shift($temp);
  return empty($item['uuid'][$key]);
}

function poh_eduref_field_formatter_info() {
  return array(
    'eduref_uuid' => array(
      'label' => t('UUID'),
      'field types' => array('eduref_uuid'),
    ),
  );
}

function poh_eduref_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {
  $element = array();
  switch ($display['type']) {
    case 'eduref_uuid' :
      foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
        if (isset($item['value'])) {
          $element[$delta]['#markup'] = $item['value'];
        }
      }
      break;
  }
  return $element;
}

/**
 * [poh_eduref_field_validate description]
 * @param  [type] $entity_type [description]
 * @param  [type] $entity      [description]
 * @param  [type] $field       [description]
 * @param  [type] $instance    [description]
 * @param  [type] $langcode    [description]
 * @param  [type] $items       [description]
 * @param  [type] $errors      [description]
 * @return [type]              [description]
 */
function poh_eduref_field_validate($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, &$errors) {
  foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
    if(empty($item['field_pec_uuid'])) {
      //$errors[$field['field_name']][$langcode][$delta][] = array('error' => 'uuid_empty_error', 'message' => t('Field empty.'));
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: For anyone who stumbles into the same issue; the solution as provided by Clive was to add a property_type key to the hook_field_info implementation, like so:

```
function poh_eduref_field_info() {
  return array(
    'eduref_uuid' => array(
      'label' => t('Eduref UUID Field'),
      'description' => t('This field stores UUID values.'),
      'settings' => array('allowed_values' => array(), 'allowed_values_function' => ''),
      'default_widget' => 'poh_eduref_eduref_widget',
      'default_formatter' => 'poh_eduref_field_formatter_view',
      'property_type' => 'text',
    ),
  );
}
```

In my case 'text' as value will suffice, as its a simple textfield. If you need more advanced examples I recommend reading the links Clive provided.

Comment: OK, you stated some facts, posted some code... But I can't see where you actually ask a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EntityMetadataWrapper` comes from the Entity API module; by default it only knows about core field types, you have to explicitly tell it how to handle custom fields.

That involves adding `property_type` and possibly `property_callbacks` keys to your field info array.

See [What does the 'property_type' key do in hook_field_info()?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34823/what-does-the-property-type-key-do-in-hook-field-info) for a bit more information, and [here](http://www.thecarneyeffect.co.uk/describe-field-properties-make-custom-fields-work-entity-metadata-wrappers) for a code sample.

Comment: Hi Clive! Thank you dear sir! Adding property_type = 'text' to my hook_field_info has solved the issue (its a simple text field)! I can access the field using entity_metadata_wrapper now!

Comment: Happy to help :)